# How to develop and test Firebase Callable functions with ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a ReactJs app with the Firebase backend and want to use https.onCall in my app. I'm starting my functions with `firebase serve --only functions`
I've got this log

> functions: HTTP trigger initialized at
>   http://localhost:5000/dental2-test/us-central1/addReportSQL

addReportSQL is my function

```
exports.addReportSQL = functions.https.onCall((data = 'TEST') => {
    console.log('TEST!!!') // Need to call cloud sql db
    return data
})
```

and have in the react app firebase this proxy

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
  app.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5000')
```

If I try to call this from my app it seems not working

```
<Button onClick={() => firebase.addReportSQL('Data')} />
```

My goal is to call queries for the Google SQL cloud service from this function.

How to make the proper setup for the local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup was right and the trick is to declare this function at first

```
const testCall = firebase.addReportSQL(data)
testCall()
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: could you please give the complete example?